# How must Google oauth hompage using restricated scopes look like

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

They are e-mailing that my homepage doesn't meet the requirements

Comment: please ask clear question

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python or Java. Please don't tag spam.

Comment: (I'm also not sure it has anything to do with _programming_.)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are working on Application verification with an app registered in google developer console.  Apps that are using restricted scopes need to be verified.

In order to apply for verification you need to supply some Urls one of them being your home page.

[image]

if google is telling you it does not meet their requirements either you added it as a http or you have not registered it in [search console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about)

[OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#verification-types&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-different-types-of-verification-that-google-requires-for-accessing-user-data-via-oauth)